# Win10 Django: NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to python and Django and use win10 system.

Django Version:1.9.4. and Python Version:3.6.3.

**In template D:\Music\music\templates\music\index.html, error at line 29**

```
19                        <div class="caption">
20                            <h2>{{ album.album_title }}</h2>
21                            <h4>{{ album.artist }}</h4>
22
23                            <!-- View Details -->
24                            <a href="{% url 'detail' album.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">View Details</a>
25
26                            <!-- Delete Album -->
27                            <form action="{% url 'delete_album' album.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">    Traceback:

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                               current_app=current_app)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'website.index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []), another exception occurred:

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Music\music\views.py" in index
  145.             return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums})

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  513.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  686.         raise value

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  499.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
28                                {% csrf_token %}
29                                <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ album.id }}" />
30                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
31                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
32                                </button>
33                            </form>
34
35                            <!-- Favorite Album -->
36                            <a href="{% url 'favorite_album' album.id %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-favorite" role="button">
37                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star {% if album.is_favorite %}active{% endif %}"></span>
38                            </a>
```

**It's the error traceback:**

> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
>     507.                               current_app=current_app)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>     600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
>     508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
>
> During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'website.index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []), another exception occurred:
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Music\music\views.py" in index
>     145.             return render(request, 'music/index.html', {'albums': albums})
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
>     67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
>     97.         return template.render(context, request)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
>     95.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     206.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
>     959.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
>     173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
>     197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
>     992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
>     959.             return self.render(context)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
>     513.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
>     686.         raise value
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
>     499.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>     600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
>
> File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
>     508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Exception Value: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

**It's my music\urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    url(r'^logout_user/$', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<song_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
    url(r'^songs/(?P<filter_by>[a-zA_Z]+)/$', views.songs, name='songs'),
    url(r'^create_album/$', views.create_album, name='create_album'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/create_song/$', views.create_song, name='create_song'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/delete_song/(?P<song_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_song, name='delete_song'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite_album/$', views.favorite_album, name='favorite_album'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/delete_album/$', views.delete_album, name='delete_album'),
]
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls'),),
    url(r'^', include('music.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you paste the error traceback ? It is unclear that where the call has happened.

Comment: Can you clarify what's going on with the last two urlpatterns? Why do both `r'^music/'` and `r'^'` use `include('music.urls')`? This isn't strictly wrong, it just seems strange/possibly redundant

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Thanks for your help, I have pasted the error traceback.

Comment: I'm new to python and Django, just follow the Youtube tourial... Should I remove one of them? @ubadub

Answer (score 1):

Namespace your music apps urls in main urls.py as:

```
url(r'^music/', include('music.urls'), namespace="music"),
```

Remove the trailing slashes from your url patterns if you have not handled that in settings for slash config

```
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

You can refer to these named url patterns in template as follows:

```
{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}
```

Comment: remove `url(r'^', include('music.urls')),` and try

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `website.index` somewhere. change it to `music:index` where `music` is the `app_name` and `index` is the url name.